# How to show Pound Symbol in Razor, MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, ascii

I am trying to display the Pound symbol to a radio button in MVC 4, However I am unable to get this ASCII code parsed.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Client.CodeID, "true", new { Name = "grp" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClientID, @Model.Price + Html.Raw("&#163"))
```

Comment: Entities need a terminating semicolon: `"&#163;"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me -

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Client.CodeID, "true", new { Name = "grp" }) 
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClientID, @Model.Price + "£")
```

Let me know if I assumed your question wrongly. My code worked for me IE and Chrome (latest versions)

Comment: What about previous version, let's say IE8+

Comment: I tried by changing compatibility modes in IE11 and it worked everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the HTML symbol for it -  `"&pound;"`